# In Dolphin file manager Fedora 17, what is the shortcut to create folder?

Tags: fedora, filesystems, kde4

In Dolphin file manager Fedora 17, what is the shortcut to create the new folder.

E.g. Ctrl + Shift + N creates new folder in Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

As per [this link](http://userbase.kde.org/Dolphin/File_Management), you have to type F10 and a create menu will appear.